# SharpDx: Setting character width

Tags: c#, c++, directx, sharpdx, directwrite

I am writing a C# Direct2D application using SharpDX, however I can understand answers/examples that are provided in C++.

I want to render text and change the width of certain characters to look like the picture:

[image]

The letter B expanded to 200% and the letter D is reduced to 50%

In the code below I draw the geometry of the glyphs
And so it is possible to change the width of geometry
But that's not a good solution, because a geometry drawing comes out as blurred as you see in the picture.

[image]

In conclusion, there are two questions:

1. How I change the width of the characters?
2. How to draw geometries of letters without blurring. (it is possible to render geometry with ClearType?)

   ```
   private void RenderGlyphRun1(FontFace1 fontFace)
   {
       var Offsets = new List<GlyphOffset>();
       var fontEmSize_ = 12;
       GlyphRun glyphRun = new GlyphRun();
       glyphRun.FontFace = fontFace;
       glyphRun.FontSize = fontEmSize_;
       glyphRun.BidiLevel = 1;
       var left = 650f;
       var top = 50f;

       var baseLine = (float)(fontFace.Metrics.LineGap + fontFace.Metrics.Ascent) /
           fontFace.Metrics.DesignUnitsPerEm * glyphRun.FontSize;

       string textToDraw = "ABCDE";
       foreach (char letter in textToDraw)
       {
           Offsets.Add(new GlyphOffset());
       }

       var charArr = textToDraw.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
       glyphRun.Indices = fontFace.GetGlyphIndices(charArr);

       var metrics = fontFace.GetDesignGlyphMetrics(glyphRun.Indices, false);
       glyphRun.Advances = metrics.Select(x => (float)x.AdvanceWidth /
                fontFace.Metrics.DesignUnitsPerEm * glyphRun.FontSize).ToArray();

       glyphRun.Offsets = Offsets.ToArray();

       RenderTarget2D.BeginDraw();
       RenderTarget2D.Clear(SharpDX.Color.White);

       RenderTarget2D.DrawGlyphRun(new Vector2(left, top),
           glyphRun, new SharpDX.Direct2D1.SolidColorBrush(RenderTarget2D, SharpDX.Color.Black),
           MeasuringMode.Natural);

       top += baseLine;

       var pathGeometry = new PathGeometry(Factory2D);
       var geometrySink = pathGeometry.Open();

       fontFace.GetGlyphRunOutline(glyphRun.FontSize, glyphRun.Indices,
           glyphRun.Advances, glyphRun.Offsets, glyphRun.IsSideways,
           glyphRun.BidiLevel % 2 != 0, geometrySink);

       geometrySink.Close();
       geometrySink.Dispose();
       fontFace.Dispose();

       var matrix = new Matrix3x2()
       {
           M11 = 1,
           M12 = 0,
           M21 = 0,
           M22 = 1,
           M31 = left,
           M32 = top
       };

       var transformedGeometry = new TransformedGeometry(Factory2D, pathGeometry, matrix);
       var brushColor = (Color4)SharpDX.Color.Black;
       var brush = new SolidColorBrush(RenderTarget2D, brushColor);
       RenderTarget2D.FillGeometry(transformedGeometry, brush);

       pathGeometry.Dispose();
       transformedGeometry.Dispose();
       brush.Dispose();

       RenderTarget2D.EndDraw();
   }
   ```

Comment: I think you need to RenderTarget2D.FillGeometry each character/glyph separately. You can also specify each glyph's scale in the matrix.

Comment: @VuVirt `You can also specify each glyph's scale in the matrix` What do you mean? Please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some of the letters should be narrow and some are normal and some are wide, you can not use one `GlyphRun`, but must create 3 different `GlyphRun`.

To cause all letters of any `GlyphRun` to be wide or narrow:

1. Configure `Transform` to `RenderTarget`
2. Draw the `GlyphRun`
3. Return the original `Transform`

Wide transform:  `RenderTarget2D.Transform = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawMatrix3x2(1.5f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

Narrow transform:  `RenderTarget2D.Transform = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawMatrix3x2(0.5f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);`

After this solution you do not need to convert `GlyphRun` to `geometry` and get mixed up with blurred letters.

Answer (score 0):

`Direct2D` text rendering functionality is offered in two parts:

1) `DrawText` and `DrawTextLayout` method, enables a caller to pass either a string and formatting parameters or a DWrite text layout object for multiple formats. This should be suitable for most callers.

2) The second way is to render text, exposed as the `DrawGlyphRun` method, provides rasterization for customers who already know the position of the glyphs they want to render. The following two general rules can help improve text performance when drawing in Direct2D.

I now see that you are using the second approach, but in the first one, you can set the rendering to `ClearType` :

```
RenderTarget2D.TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Cleartype;
```

I am not sure how to include it in you example, but the Sharp DX example looks like this:

```
using System;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.DirectWrite;
using SharpDX.Samples;
using TextAntialiasMode = SharpDX.Direct2D1.TextAntialiasMode;

namespace TextRenderingApp
{
  public class Program : Direct2D1DemoApp
  {        
    public TextFormat TextFormat { get; private set; }
    public TextLayout TextLayout { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(DemoConfiguration demoConfiguration)
    {
        base.Initialize(demoConfiguration);

        // Initialize a TextFormat
        TextFormat = new TextFormat(FactoryDWrite, "Calibri", 128) {TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, ParagraphAlignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center};

        RenderTarget2D.TextAntialiasMode = TextAntialiasMode.Cleartype;

        // Initialize a TextLayout
        TextLayout = new TextLayout(FactoryDWrite, "SharpDX D2D1 - DWrite", TextFormat, demoConfiguration.Width, demoConfiguration.Height);
    }


    protected override void Draw(DemoTime time)
    {
        base.Draw(time);

        // Draw the TextLayout
        RenderTarget2D.DrawTextLayout(new Vector2(0,0), TextLayout, SceneColorBrush, DrawTextOptions.None );
    }


    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.Run(new DemoConfiguration("SharpDX DirectWrite Text Rendering Demo"));
    }
  }
}
```

Sample taken from: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/TextRenderingApp

Comment: Please explain to me how your answer answers my questions? `How I change the width of the characters?
How to draw geometries of letters without blurring. (it is possible to render geometry with ClearType?)`

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is not enough